# obtener el valor de return de una funcion y pasarcelo a otra

Tags: javascript, funciones

¿es posible obtener el valor de return de la funcion prueba y pasarcela a la funcion prueba2 sin variables?

```
function prueba(){
return "prueba 1";
}
function prueba2(){
alert(aqui quiero que aparesca el return);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes mandarlo como parámetro dentro de la función o de esta manera

```js
function prueba(){
return "prueba 1";
}
function prueba2(){
alert(prueba());
}

prueba2();
```

de esta forma el alert mostrará el return de prueba

Answer (score 1):

Claro puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, enviarlo como parametro dentro de la funcion.

```js
function prueba(){
  return prueba2("prueba 1");
}

function prueba2(dato){
alert(dato);
}

prueba()
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
function foo() {
    return 'foo';
}

function bar(arg) {
    return arg;
}

console.log(bar(foo());
```

O tambien podrias:

```javascript
const val_foo = foo();

console.log(bar(val_foo);
```

La funcion `foo()` retorna el string `foo` y la function `bar()` acepta un argumento y lo retorna